# In the production environment, the Client is not getting the response they need to get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, exception

I wrote this AppError class that will suffice my global error handling middleware in sending responses on both operational and programming errors.

```
class AppError extends Error {
     constructor(message, statusCode){
          super(message);

          this.statusCode = statusCode;
          this.status = `${statusCode}`.startsWith(4) ? 'fail' : 'error';
          this.isOperational = true;

          Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
     }
}

module.exports = AppError;
```

And here is my global error handling middleware with all necessary functions to make it work.

```
const AppError = require('./AppError');


//global error handling middleware all errors go into it
module.exports = (err, req, res, next)=>{
     err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
     err.status = err.status || 'error';

     if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
          sendErrorDev(err, res)
     }

     else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
          let error = {...err};
          if(error.name === 'CastError') error = handleCastErrorDB(error);
          sendErrorProd(err, res)
     }
};


const sendErrorDev = (err, res) => {
     res.status(err.statusCode).json({
          status: err.status,
          error: err,
          message: err.message,
          stack: err.stack
     });
}

const sendErrorProd = (err, res) => {
     // Operational, trusted error: send message to client
     if (err.isOperational){
          res.status(err.statusCode).json({
               status: err.status,
               message: err.message
          });
     }else{
          // Programming or other unknown error: don't send details to client
          //1_console err
          console.log('error: ', err);
          //2_send generic message to client
          res.status(500).json({
               status: 'error',
               message: 'Something went very wrong!'
          });
     };
};

const handleCastErrorDB = err => {
     const message = `Invalid ${err.path}: ${err.value}`;
     return new AppError(message, 400)
};
```

My problem is, in the production environment when I'm trying to get the data through a GET request, the client is not getting the error that they should get, I'm testing it with the postman. Elaborating more, to test what's the client is getting I'm trying to get the data with the invalid ID...

```
127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/tours/wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

That's the client mistake and therefore, they should get the response as set in `handleCastErrorDB` with 400 status code but instead, I'm seeing 500 status code with message

```
"status": "error",
    "message": "Something went very wrong!"
```

That's the response the client would get if the error is not operational. See in `sendErrorProd()` function.

In development mode, I'm getting the thing I want but tucked here.

I'm in learning mode in node.js and I've tried everything in my knowledge.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

First, in the code below. In the latest version of mongoose, I think **error.name** is not exist directly.

The issue is that when you copy the err object using the spread operator, you are not copying its non-enumerable properties, such as **name**. This means that your **error.name** will be **undefined** in the production environment, and your error handling logic **will not work** as expected.

```js
//global error handling middleware all errors go into it
module.exports = (err, req, res, next)=>{
     err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
     err.status = err.status || 'error';

     if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
          sendErrorDev(err, res)
     }

     else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
          let error = {...err};
          if(error.name === 'CastError') error = handleCastErrorDB(error);
          sendErrorProd(err, res)
     }
};
```

To fix this, you need to copy the name property explicitly, like this:

You should replace this line:

```js
let error = {...err};
```

With this:

```js
let error = { ...err, name: err.name };
```

This way, **your error.name will be preserved** and your **handleCastErrorDB** function will be called correctly.

---

Second, I don't know why, but the reason that there is no response in production mode is that you are running the server with nodemon script (I think that is it:
`"start:prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production & nodemon server.js"`

This with some reason will not make it send the response when you make a request.

So, **to solve this problem**, just edit `NODE_ENV=development` to `NODE_ENV=production` from **config.env** file **manually**.

**Then,** from VSCode terminal, run `npm start` not `npm run start:prod`.

Or **if you still want to use the script instead editing **config.env** manually,** you just need to **make a little changes** to work just fine. Here is what you should do:

1. Install cross-env npm package globally `npm install cross-env --global`.
2. Instead of the previous script, just add this script `"start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js"`.
3. Run the script `npm run start:prod`

I hope that helps you a bit.